# Rails3.1: Options in a custom validator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I wrote this custom validator:

```
class SecureTokenValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    Rails.logger.debug("validate_each options: #{options.inspect}")
  end
end
```

And here the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  attr_accessor :token

  validates_length_of :password, minimum: 6
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  validates :token, secure_token: {attributes: %w(salutation first_name last_name) }
end
```

But the options are not passed to validator, here the entry from the log:

```
validate_each options: {}
```

Why? I'm using Rails 3.1.1 on Ruby 1.9.2p290

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to choose a different name than `attributes` for my option. Now it's called `attribute_order` and works fine.

Comment: Future Googler, if you're passing a proc (or regex) in your custom attribute this wont work and you need to use the provided `option` key `:with`